# How to swap product image that is already in cart depending on selected product option?

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller, magento-1.3

recently I was needed to enhance Magento (1.3.1) user interface. Particularly add a product image switcher (following http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/create-a-color-switcher-in-magento/).

The results:
- image switcher works as expected, which is fine.

The problem:
- The product itself could hold as much as 15 or 20 colors-images to choose from.

The goal:
- when the user choose the product color using "select" element, the selected product color must swap default product color to show it in cart.

I was thinking to use a session to hold the selected data and then swap it, but it looks way to complicated, because image directories holds as cache directories and I don't know the exact path when viewing the image.

Second idea was to swap from checkout/cart controller using /checkout/cart/item/default.phtml, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: no one? Does it sounds too difficult?

Answer (score 0):

If You use Configurable product with associated Simple products user will add to cart simple product instead configurable. Every Simple product can have different attributes (ex: color)